# Multilist items render on MVC view by razor sysntax

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a footer template that have Title, Description and links. Links are multi-list. I need to render the selected items from links multi-list with Title and description on footer view.

I know how we can do it by using Model rendering but is there is any other simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What type of rendering are you using? If you're not using a controller rendering, I would recommend using that and building a view model with all the fully-hydrated model items attached to it.

Comment: With multilist or fields which will store references, you have to do orchestration at code level and need to share model which can be directly render on page. I think no direct mode which will directly provide multilist values.

Comment: Also you can utilize  Glass Mapper OR Synthesis Sitecore ORM (Object Relation Mapping) Template